# Field 0 Value for Null

Tags: delphi

I have lookup field, how to set 0 value when the field is null ?
as we know, a field that does not have a value will have a BLANK in dbgrid.

I can try to make calculated field like this :

```
if lookupfield1.Value = 0 then
  calcfield.Value := 0 
else 
calcfield.Value := lookupfield1.Value;
```

But I will have many calculated fields to create.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how you can make a grid display "0" instead of BLANK when a TIntegerField contains null.

A more simple approach than calc fields would be to use the OnGetText event

```
procedure TForm2.ClientDataSet1F1GetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string;
  DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Text := IntToStr(Sender.AsInteger)
end;
```

I've toyed with the DisplayFormat property... but it doesn't seem to affect the display format for null values. (Not in TDBGrid at least...)

Answer (score 3):

Use the TField.Clear method to set a database field to NULL (a NULL value in SQL terms).

```
if lookupfield1.Value = 0 then
  calcfield.Clear
else 
  calcfield.Value := lookupfield1.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if lookupfield1.Value = null then
  calcfield.Value := 0 
else 
  calcfield.Value := lookupfield1.Value;
```

Instead of using calculated fields, as an alternative, you could set the field value to 0 in the BeforePost of the dataset if field value is null.

```
procedure tMyTableBeforePost(Dataset: TDataset);
begin
  if Dataset.fieldbyname('MyField').asstring = '' then 
    Dataset.fieldbyname('MyField').asstring := '0';
end;
```

I avoid calculated fields whenever I can.

If your database supports it, you can set the default value of the field to 0 at the table configuration level.